# Spring session factory not finding mapping files in multiple directories with same class path

Tags: spring, hibernate, classpath

I am having problems when loading hibernate mappings from multiple paths.

My Spring session factory is define as follows:

```
<beans>
  ...
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframwork.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactory">
  </bean>

  <property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:/mapping/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
```

When I put my mappings `Foo.hbm.xml` and `Bar.hbm.xml` into the directory `src/main/resources/mappings`, then both mappings are found when Hibernate is initialized.

But when I put `Foo.hbm.xml` into the directory `src/main/resources/mapping` and `Bar.hbm.xml` into the directory `src/test/resources/mapping`, then only the latter mapping file can be found. Hibernate will fail with "cannot find mapping for Foo" error.

I can see that the mappings are copied to the directories `target/classes/mapping` and `target/test-classes/mapping`, so why cannot hibernate (or the spring local session factory bean) find both mapping files? I thought that "classpath:/mapping/*.hbm.xml" would find both `target/classes/mapping` and `target/test-classes/mapping` directories?

edit: I am getting this problem when running unit tests, so I expect that mappings found in both `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` would be found.

Answer (score 0):

You are using maven. And since you put your Bar mapping into the *test resource directory*, it is only available when running tests.

I assume you have a persistence-unit configured similar to the example below

```
<persistence-unit ...>
    <class>something.Foo</class>
    <class>something.Bar</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

What happens at start-up is that Spring starts Hibernate, hibernates reads the persistence-unit and asks the factory for the mappings. But remember, Bar is only a test class. So Spring finds the mappings from `src/main/resources`, but since it does not run as a test, it does not see `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have indicated that I am getting this problem when I run my tests, so I do expect mappings defined in the test resource directory to be found, in addition to the mappings defined in the main resource directory. When I run my tests with all mappings in `src/main/resources`, then all mappings are found. When I run my tests with one mapping moved from `src/main/resources` to `src/test/resources`, then only the mapping found in `src/test/resources` is found.